# why the SDWebImage'downloader use concurrent queue to save callbacks?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

Why doesn't SD use "serial queue" or "synchrolock",SD use like this,dispatch_barrier_async

```
   _barrierQueue=dispatch_queue_create("com.hackemist.SDWebImageDownloaderBarrierQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_barrier_sync(self.barrierQueue, ^{
      ....
});
dispatch_barrier_async(sself.barrierQueue, ^{
   [sself.URLCallbacks removeObjectForKey:url];
});
dispatch_sync(sself.barrierQueue, ^{
   callbacksForURL = [sself.URLCallbacks[url] copy];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; For a better performance.

1. A write operation (including removal) must be an atom operation, so their are wrapped in a barrier block
2. A read operation can be parallel, so their are wrapped in a sync block, to improve multi-core performance